# android webview - footer in the middle?

Tags: android, webview, footer

I use a Web View to show a website. When I scroll to the bottom of the page, I see the footer in the middle of the screen. Its like a picture of the footer. When i touch it, it disappears.

Edit 1:
First I'm scrolling to the bottom of the page. The i click a Link on the footer. After the webpage is loaded, when i now scroll to the middle of the page, i see like a screenshot of the footer. When i now touch on this , it disappears.. When i look this website with the standard browser of the mobile device - it works.

EDIT 2:

I did it. For those who have the same problem.

Meta Tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;"/>
```

And this in the App:

```
WebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
WebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Comment: Can you please provide any screenshot and code snippet?? that will be helpful to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First cross-check your application with this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) , also refer [Building Web Apps in WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)**

Comment: I used these links. And i checked the code. I first thought, its the HTML Code, but on the default browser on the mobile device it works.